# Override QPushButton to provide additional text

Tags: python, pyqt, qpushbutton

I just want to extend a QPushButton so it would store an additional long string that I need afterwards.

Comment: `button.longString = 'my very long string'`?

Comment: @musicamante Not sure to understand. longstring does not exist from the base QPushButton

Comment: You can create attributes for objects, if `button` is an instance of QPushButton, create a custom attribute with your string.

Comment: indeed, this is my question : how to add custom attribute then

Comment: Then do exactly as in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyQt built-in classes support dynamic attributes, just like ordinary user-defined Python classes:

```
>>> button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
>>> button.foo = 'bar'
>>> print(button.foo)
bar
```

However, you could also use [QObject properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property), since `QPushButton` inherits `QObject` (via `QWidget`):

```
>>> button.setProperty('extra', 'additional long string')
>>> button.property('extra')
'additional long string'
```

One significant difference of this approach, is that unset properties will always return `None`, rather than raising an error:

```
>>> button.property('whatever') is None
True
```